# System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime - when trying to convert MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, webforms

I have following C# method:

```
DateTime ConvertStringToDate(string dateInString)
    {
        try {
            //string SSD = dateInString;
            //DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(SSD);
            //string strDate = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", date);
            //return Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);
    
            return DateTime.ParseExact(dateInString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return DateTime.Today;
    }
```

The code in comment is another way I tried before.

I am in India and developing an ASP.NET WebForms application for my client in US. On one of its forms my client will enter the date in `TextBox` like **6/20/2018** which is **MM/dd/yyyy** format.

But, in both the ways I am getting this error:

```
System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
```

Comment: @Rafalon Sorry I tried to test it using time. Forgot to remove it. It's also not working for date only.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `dateInString`? _Don't guess, debug it and check._

Comment: `MM/dd/yyyy` format would require your date to be `06/20/2018` and still `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` can't work for date-only strings

Comment: @mjwills the value is 6/20/2018 when debugging.

Comment: Then how do you expect `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` to match this?

Comment: @Rafalon oh sorry i again forgot to remove the time from format. I tried only date too in the format before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
return DateTime.ParseExact(dateInString, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Check it here](http://tpcg.io/JZCvKW)

The difference between my answer and Fabulous' one is that I also shortened `dd` to `d` so if your user writes `6/6/2018` it will work too

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva yes it does

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva Why would you ask that. Why wouldn't you just *test* it?

Comment: @mason I actually asked myself the same question as you did, especially since I included a link where you can basically change the input and hit "Execute"

Comment: @mason I was actually in a hurry. So read the answer without noticing the link and the example.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your date format is MM/dd/yyyy and your input doesn't match. It is M/dd/yyyy

Based on your comment, to solve the 6/1/2018 issue, you'll need to do it as follows M/d/yyyy

Comment: Tried this format for "6/1/2018" but it's not working.

Comment: @Rafalon after seeing the OP's comment and sorting this, I saw and upvoted your answer. I had not seen it when I was editing my original answer which referenced the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your format string is missing the AM/PM deisgnator:

```
return DateTime.ParseExact
    (dateInString + " 12:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    // Here ---------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Sorry I tried to test it using time. Forgot to remove it. It's also not working for date only.. See the update.

Answer (score 1):

Try without concatenation with string " AM"

Comment: Sorry I tried to test it using time. Forgot to remove it. It's also not working for date only. See the update.

Comment: You fill out MM/dd/yyyy but use this "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" pattern

Comment: Try to use "MM/dd/yyyy" only

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same exception a couple of days ago when it was 9th of July, I simply appended a 0 with 9 to match the date format.

Try appending a 0 in your month to match the MM in your date format

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your system time and date format is not same as test format you can try to change system date and time format

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert this (01-01-2022) type of string into date
then try below code.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("01-01-2022", "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to convert this (01/01/2022) type of string into date
then try below code.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("01-01-2022", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```